# Generate a random integer on an interval

Tags: java, random, integer

So I have this class called Organism:

```
public class Organism implements Comparable{

    // Represents the organisms guess for the unknown string
    String value;
    // String the organism is trying to guess
    String goalString;
    int n;

    public Organism(String goalString) {
        this.goalString = goalString;
        this.value = goalString;
    }

    public Organism(String value, String goalString, int n) {
        this.goalString = goalString;
        this.value = value;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int fitness(){
        // Represents the fitness of the organism
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < goalString.length(); i++) {
            if(value.charAt(i) == goalString.charAt(i)) {
                count ++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public Organism[] mate(Organism other) {
        // Generate a random integer from [0, n-1]
        int crossOver;



        return new Organism[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        return 0;
    }

    public void mutate(double mutateProb) {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value: " + value + "    " + "Goal: " + goalString + "    " + "Fitness: " + fitness();
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getGoalString() {
        return goalString;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

}
```

Inside of the mate method I need to generate a random integer on the interval [0, n-1] where n is the length of value and goalString. I then need to store that inside of the crossOver variable inside of the mate method. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the thing:

```
int n = other.getValue().length() + other.getGoalString().length();
Random rand = new Random();
int crossOver = rand.nextInt(n);
```

If you meant `n` should be the sum of the `value` and `goalStrng` of the current (`this`) object, simply remove the `other.` or replace it with `this.`.

All have to be placed in the `public Organism[] mate(Organism other)` method.